# What signal to emit when data behind QAbstractTableModel has changed completely?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I tried to figure out what event should be emmited when my [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) model has completely new data. There are methods `modelAboutToBeReset()`, `modelReset()`, and `endResetModel()`. Do I really need to call each of them in that order and why? Wouldn't one call of `modelReset()` not be enough? It would suffice to inform the view that everything is new and its content shall be re-fetched.

Comment: If you implement model reset yourself you need to call `beginResetModel()` before invalidating the model and `endResetModel()` after. `modelReset()` signal is emitted after you call `QAbstractItemModel::reset()` function.

Comment: so what is the right order? beginResetModel(), modelReset, endResetModel()

Comment: Signal names already tell you the order: `beginResetModel(); /* do reset */ endResetModel();`. As I said, calling `modelReset()` is not needed if you implement reset yourself.